# Finding Counter Examples

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that the following is false:

If $x_n \to 0$, then $\dfrac{1}{x_n} \to  \infty$ as $n \to  \infty.$

However, I can't come up with a counter. My thinking is that if $x_n$ is converging to zero, then $x_n$ must be in the denominator. But, when you reciprocate that then it is just $x_n$ which does in fact converge to $\infty.$

Comment: I think you can observe $x_n=(-1)^n/n$

Comment: Why do you write $\infty$ instead of $+\infty$?

Comment: @Cornman so, with that example since it diverges to -∞ that is a counter? I guess that makes sense. I was thinking very narrowly and trying to find a counter that converged to a finite number.

Comment: @Liza Certainly if $x_n \to 0$, then $1/x_n$ is unbounded, so you won't find an example where $1/x_n$ converges to a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What if all or some of the $x_n$ terms are negative?